# How do protons transfer from one object to another by induction?

Tags: charge, electrons, electromagnetic-induction, protons

Charging by induction begins with a positively charged object and a neutral object which causes the electrons on the neutral object to be closer to the charged object. In diagrams I saw online, when the neutral object is grounded the (what I'm assuming are) protons move away from the negatively charged object, then the *protons* transfer from one object to the ground, or another object. I thought that protons couldn't move from the nuclei of the atom. How are they being transferred? Or are they representing atoms that are more positively charged?

[image]

For example, an image like this except the charges are reversed.

Comment: The minus signs signify regions with an excess of electrons. The plus signs signify regions with a deficit of electrons. Both are created by the movement of electrons. The protons don't move.

Answer (score 2):

You are misinterpreting the diagrams.  In most cases (particularly those involving ordinary conductive metallic solids) any local positive net charge is due to a deficit of electrons, not a surfeit of protons.  Often, it does make sense to think of there being moving positive charge carriers, but these are "holes" formed by the absence of atomic electrons, not protons in motion.  Essentially all the movement of charges is due to changes in the electron configuration, with the protons remaining essentially stationary.